# multiple promises from a forEach function

Tags: node.js

What I basically want is to loop a promise so that I can output and array of the results.

```
  var oracle_table = new oracle_driver(tableName);

  var promise = new Promise(queryObject, function(resolve, reject) {
    oracle_table.query(queryObject, (err, result) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  })

  Promise.all(vals.forEach((queryObject) => promise(queryObject)))
    .then((results) => {
      // results expected to be [result, result, result] from var promise
      res.status(200).json(results)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    })
```

`oracle_driver` is a class that connects to the database.

`tableName` is the name of table that is being edited.

`.query` is a function that gets an object, translates it and query the database returning the results. below is the code of `.query`:

```
    // query
  query(queryObject, callback) {
    queryObject = JSON.parse(queryObject) // Make sure that the object is in JSON format
    let table = this.tableName; // decaring the name of the table from the constructor
    let query = `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE `; // declaring the beginning query
    // Splitting the data from the object in arrays of there keys and there values
    let keys = Object.keys(queryObject);
    var values = Object.keys(queryObject).map(function(key) {
      return queryObject[key];
    });
    let frist = true;
    // constructing the two new arrays into a string
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (!frist) query = query.concat(`AND (${keys[i]} = '${values[i]}')`)
      else query = query.concat(`(${keys[i]} = '${values[i]}')`)
      frist = false;
    }
    // Showing the query
    console.log('query'+query);
    console.log('connecting to db');
    // Get a non-pooled connection
    oracledb.getConnection(
      databaseDetails, // DB connection details
      function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
        connection.execute(query,
          {

          },
          function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.error(err.message);
            console.log('results from db driver ----');
            console.log(result.rows);
            callback(err, result.rows); // Callback with db details 
            doRelease(connection); // close connection
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where does `oracle_driver` come from? This code is obfuscating a lot of important details. For example, are you using a single connection or does each query get its own connection from a pool? If a single connection, then this will not work anyway because a connection can only execute one statement at a time. You will end up locking threads in the thread pool unnecessarily. See these for details: https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAdeljxq_hs.

Comment: I added the code. Thank you for the in-site of the node model hopefully I will understand my issue better

Comment: Be careful when you're taking values from users to construct SQL queries - it can open you up to SQL injection. Where does this.tableName come from? If it's from a user, then you should sanitize or check it against a valid list of table names before using it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to wrap your promise into a function, so that you can send your queries to it.

Second, you need to use `map` instead of `forEach`, as you need to give the `Promise.all` a list of Promises, not just call your functions there.

This is the final answer that should work:

```
var promise = (queryObject) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        oracle_table.query(queryObject, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};

vals = [query1, query2, query3, ...];

Promise.all(vals.map(el => promise(el)))
.then(result => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

Comment: this didn't work. I got this error: `TypeError: Promise resolver {"ID_FACTURA":"55555"} is not a function`.  `{"ID_FACTURA":"55555"}` is stored in vals (I only tested it with one for this case)

Comment: what is your queryObject type?

Comment: This was almost the solution but oracle_table.query was creating an other tread inside the class oracle_table

Comment: but the issue that i showed you before just left I must have do a mistake myself